# Why is the javascript method not being called from the form button click?

Tags: javascript

Why will this function not be called on a click event from a button in a form. I have see no reason that this would not be called from the click event. Everything is at a global level which I am not certain is either good or bad.

Code:

```
function hex_md5(s)
{ 
    return binl2hex(core_md5(str2binl(s), 
                    s.length * chrsz));
}

    <form>
      <td>
        <font color=#00FF00 size=3>Input</font>  
      </td>
      <td > 
        <input type=text name=input1 size=60>
        </br>
      </td>
      <td>    
        <font color=#000000 size=3>Result</font> 
      </td>
      <td> 
        <input type=text name=hash size=60>
        </br>
      </td>
      <td>  
        <input type=button value="MD5 It!" onclick="hash.value = hex_md5(input1.value)">
        </br>
      </td> 
    </form>
```

Problem:

```
function binl2str(bin)
{
  var str = "";
  var mask = (1 << chrsz) - 1;
  for(var i = 0; i < bin.length * 32; i += chrsz)
    str += String.fromCharCode((bin[i>>5] >>> (i % 32)) & mask);
    if (str == "") {
        return "Empty String";
    } else {
        return str;
    }
}
```

This code is return an empty string or a null value.

Below is the whole code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>MD5 Hashing</title>
  </head>
<body>

<script language="JavaScript">

var hexcase = 0;
var b64pad  = "";
var chrsz   = 8; 

function hex_md5(s){ 
    console.log("hex md5");

    console.log(binl2hex(core_md5(str2binl(s), s.length * chrsz)));
    return binl2hex(core_md5(str2binl(s), s.length * chrsz));
}

function b64_md5(s){ 
    return binl2b64(core_md5(str2binl(s), s.length * chrsz));
}

function str_md5(s){ 
    return binl2str(core_md5(str2binl(s), s.length * chrsz));
}

function hex_hmac_md5(key, data){ 
    return binl2hex(core_hmac_md5(key, data)); 
}

function b64_hmac_md5(key, data){ 
    return binl2b64(core_hmac_md5(key, data)); 
}

function str_hmac_md5(key, data){ 
    return binl2str(core_hmac_md5(key, data)); 
}

function core_md5(x, len){
  x[len >> 5] |= 0x80 << ((len) % 32);
  x[(((len + 64) >>> 9) << 4) + 14] = len;

  var a =  1732584193;
  var b = -271733879;
  var c = -1732584194;
  var d =  271733878;

  for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i += 16){
    var olda = a;
    var oldb = b;
    var oldc = c;
    var oldd = d;

    a = md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 0], 7 , -680876936);
    d = md5_ff(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 1], 12, -389564586);
    c = md5_ff(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 2], 17,  606105819);
    b = md5_ff(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 3], 22, -1044525330);
    a = md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 4], 7 , -176418897);
    d = md5_ff(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 5], 12,  1200080426);
    c = md5_ff(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 6], 17, -1473231341);
    b = md5_ff(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 7], 22, -45705983);
    a = md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 8], 7 ,  1770035416);
    d = md5_ff(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 9], 12, -1958414417);
    c = md5_ff(c, d, a, b, x[i+10], 17, -42063);
    b = md5_ff(b, c, d, a, x[i+11], 22, -1990404162);
    a = md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x[i+12], 7 ,  1804603682);
    d = md5_ff(d, a, b, c, x[i+13], 12, -40341101);
    c = md5_ff(c, d, a, b, x[i+14], 17, -1502002290);
    b = md5_ff(b, c, d, a, x[i+15], 22,  1236535329);

    a = md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 1], 5 , -165796510);
    d = md5_gg(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 6], 9 , -1069501632);
    c = md5_gg(c, d, a, b, x[i+11], 14,  643717713);
    b = md5_gg(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 0], 20, -373897302);
    a = md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 5], 5 , -701558691);
    d = md5_gg(d, a, b, c, x[i+10], 9 ,  38016083);
    c = md5_gg(c, d, a, b, x[i+15], 14, -660478335);
    b = md5_gg(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 4], 20, -405537848);
    a = md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 9], 5 ,  568446438);
    d = md5_gg(d, a, b, c, x[i+14], 9 , -1019803690);
    c = md5_gg(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 3], 14, -187363961);
    b = md5_gg(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 8], 20,  1163531501);
    a = md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x[i+13], 5 , -1444681467);
    d = md5_gg(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 2], 9 , -51403784);
    c = md5_gg(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 7], 14,  1735328473);
    b = md5_gg(b, c, d, a, x[i+12], 20, -1926607734);

    a = md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 5], 4 , -378558);
    d = md5_hh(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 8], 11, -2022574463);
    c = md5_hh(c, d, a, b, x[i+11], 16,  1839030562);
    b = md5_hh(b, c, d, a, x[i+14], 23, -35309556);
    a = md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 1], 4 , -1530992060);
    d = md5_hh(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 4], 11,  1272893353);
    c = md5_hh(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 7], 16, -155497632);
    b = md5_hh(b, c, d, a, x[i+10], 23, -1094730640);
    a = md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x[i+13], 4 ,  681279174);
    d = md5_hh(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 0], 11, -358537222);
    c = md5_hh(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 3], 16, -722521979);
    b = md5_hh(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 6], 23,  76029189);
    a = md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 9], 4 , -640364487);
    d = md5_hh(d, a, b, c, x[i+12], 11, -421815835);
    c = md5_hh(c, d, a, b, x[i+15], 16,  530742520);
    b = md5_hh(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 2], 23, -995338651);

    a = md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 0], 6 , -198630844);
    d = md5_ii(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 7], 10,  1126891415);
    c = md5_ii(c, d, a, b, x[i+14], 15, -1416354905);
    b = md5_ii(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 5], 21, -57434055);
    a = md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x[i+12], 6 ,  1700485571);
    d = md5_ii(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 3], 10, -1894986606);
    c = md5_ii(c, d, a, b, x[i+10], 15, -1051523);
    b = md5_ii(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 1], 21, -2054922799);
    a = md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 8], 6 ,  1873313359);
    d = md5_ii(d, a, b, c, x[i+15], 10, -30611744);
    c = md5_ii(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 6], 15, -1560198380);
    b = md5_ii(b, c, d, a, x[i+13], 21,  1309151649);
    a = md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 4], 6 , -145523070);
    d = md5_ii(d, a, b, c, x[i+11], 10, -1120210379);
    c = md5_ii(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 2], 15,  718787259);
    b = md5_ii(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 9], 21, -343485551);

    a = safe_add(a, olda);
    b = safe_add(b, oldb);
    c = safe_add(c, oldc);
    d = safe_add(d, oldd);
  }
  return md5_ff(a, b, c, d);
}

function md5_cmn(q, a, b, x, s, t)
{
  return safe_add(bit_rol(safe_add(safe_add(a, q), safe_add(x, t)), s),b);
}

function md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x, s, t)
{
  return md5_cmn((b & c) | ((~b) & d), a, b, x, s, t);
}

function md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x, s, t)
{
  return md5_cmn((b & d) | (c & (~d)), a, b, x, s, t);
}

function md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x, s, t)
{
  return md5_cmn(b ^ c ^ d, a, b, x, s, t);
}

function md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x, s, t)
{
  return md5_cmn(c ^ (b | (~d)), a, b, x, s, t);
}

function core_hmac_md5(key, data)
{
  var bkey = str2binl(key);
  if(bkey.length > 16) 
    bkey = core_md5(bkey, key.length * chrsz);

  var ipad = Array(16), opad = Array(16);

  for(var i = 0; i < 16; i++)
  {
    ipad[i] = bkey[i] ^ 0x36363636;
    opad[i] = bkey[i] ^ 0x5C5C5C5C;
  }

  var hash = core_md5(ipad.concat(str2binl(data)), 512 + data.length * chrsz);
  return core_md5(opad.concat(hash), 512 + 128);
}

function safe_add(x, y)
{
  var lsw = (x & 0xFFFF) + (y & 0xFFFF);
  var msw = (x >> 16) + (y >> 16) + (lsw >> 16);
  return (msw << 16) | (lsw & 0xFFFF);
}

function bit_rol(num, cnt)
{
  return (num << cnt) | (num >>> (32 - cnt));
}

function str2binl(str)
{
  var bin = Array();
  var mask = (1 << chrsz) - 1;
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length * chrsz; i += chrsz) {
    bin[i>>5] |= (str.charCodeAt(i / chrsz) & mask) << (i%32);
  }
  return bin;
}

function binl2str(bin)
{
  var str = "";
  var mask = (1 << chrsz) - 1;
  for(var i = 0; i < bin.length * 32; i += chrsz)
    str += String.fromCharCode((bin[i>>5] >>> (i % 32)) & mask);
    if (str == "") {
        return "Empty String";
    } else {
        return str;
    }
}

function binl2hex(binarray)
{
console.log("bin 12 hex");
  var hex_tab = hexcase ? "0123456789ABCDEF" : "0123456789abcdef";
  var str = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < binarray.length * 4; i++)
  {
    str += hex_tab.charAt((binarray[i>>2] >> ((i%4)*8+4)) & 0xF) +
           hex_tab.charAt((binarray[i>>2] >> ((i%4)*8  )) & 0xF);
  }
console.log("str: " + str);  
  return str;
}

function binl2b64(binarray)
{
  var tab = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
  var str = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < binarray.length * 4; i += 3)
  {
    var triplet = (((binarray[i   >> 2] >> 8 * ( i   %4)) & 0xFF) << 16)
                | (((binarray[i+1 >> 2] >> 8 * ((i+1)%4)) & 0xFF) << 8 )
                |  ((binarray[i+2 >> 2] >> 8 * ((i+2)%4)) & 0xFF);
    for(var j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
      if(i * 8 + j * 6 > binarray.length * 32) 
      {
        str += b64pad;
      }
      else 
      {
        str += tab.charAt((triplet >> 6*(3-j)) & 0x3F);
      }
    }
  }
  return str;
}
</script>

    <form>
      <td>
        <font color=#00FF00 size=3>Input</font>  
      </td>
      <td > 
        <input type=text name=input1 size=60>
        </br>
      </td>
      <td>    
        <font color=#000000 size=3>Result</font> 
      </td>
      <td> 
        <input type=text name=hash size=60>
        </br>
      </td>
      <td>  
        <input type=button value="MD5 It!" onclick="hash.value = hex_md5(input1.value)">
      </td> 
    </form>

    <form>
      <td>
        <font color=#FF0000 size=3>Input</font>
      </td>
      <td> 
        <input type=text name=input2 size=60></br>
      </td>
      <td>    
        <font color=#000000 size=3>Result</font> 
      </td>
      <td > 
        <input type=text name=hash size=60></br>
      </td>
      <td>    
        <input type=button value="MD64 It!" onclick="hash.value = b64_md5(input2.value)">
      </td>     
    </form>

    <form>
      <font color=#0000FF size=3>Input</font>  </td><td > <input type=text name=input3 size=60><br>
      <font color=#000000 size=3>Result</font> </td><td > <input type=text name=hash size=60><br>
      <input type=button value="str_MD5 It!" onclick="hash.value = str_md5(input3.value)">
    </form>

    <form>
      <font color=#0000FF size=3>Input</font>  </td><td > <input type=text name=input4 size=60><br>
      <font color=#000000 size=3>Result</font> </td><td > <input type=text name=hash size=60><br>
        <font color=#000000 size=3>Key Salt</font> </td><td > <input type=text name=salt size=60><br>
      <input type=button value="core_hmac_md5 It!" onclick="hash.value = core_hmac_md5('a',input4.value)">
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably get a reference error since neither `hash` or `input1` are defined. Read these articles to [learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging), so you can provider more useful context information (and help yourself).

Comment: What makes you think it's not being called?

Comment: @FelixKling `hash` and `input1` are the names of the `input` elements, they're accessible as variables.

Comment: Oh I missed the `hash `one.

Comment: [Gets called just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/pevans02/G4WRv/), but there are reference errors for `binl2hex`, `core_md5`, `str2binl` where are these functions, and variable `chrsz`?

Comment: And the <script></script> tags? , add some console.log("something"), into the function, use the browser console to inspect, what is happening.

Comment: give us a fiddle link

Comment: Are you trying to use http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_bin2hex.asp php function?

Comment: Mmm i not understand what are you  trying to do, but if you want use Javascript, you should add the <script> tags wrapping the code, in this case, you should define too, the others functions you are want to use.
If you are trying to write php you need add <?php tags wrapping the code, in this case, you will not able to call the php function from click event of a button, you should call a javascript  function.

Comment: provide the code of ur binl2hex() function

Comment: Is this RSA Data Security base algorithim or some sort of encryption algorithm

Comment: Well, it appears that for some reason one of the functions is return a null value. But i was wrong in the my first thought. The function is being called but there is a function that is not returning any value. My question was answered. If someone wants to see if they can get all of the forms buttons to return a value I am going to offer a bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will work. However, you need to check your md5 function by yourself since I don't have it

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function hex_md5()
{ 
    var s = document.getElementById("input1");
    var s1 = document.getElementById("hash");
    //s1.value = replace it with md5 call;
    s1.value =s.value;
}
</script>
<body>
    <form>
      <td>
        <font color=#00FF00 size=3>Input</font>  
      </td>
      <td > 
        <input type=text name=input1 id="input1" size=60>
        </br>
      </td>
      <td>    
        <font color=#000000 size=3>Result</font> 
      </td>
      <td> 
        <input type=text id="hash" name=hash size=60>
        </br>
      </td>
      <td>  
        <input type=button value="MD5 It!" onclick="hex_md5()">
        </br>
      </td> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, remove the code line s1.value =s.value; when you place a call to md5 function.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this if you are trying to do Rsa Based encryption.

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="globe/script/jquery.js"></script>
                <title>
                    Html5 All in One
                </title>
                <style>

                </style>
            </head>
            <body >


        <!--1 Column Photo-->

            <form>
              <td>
                <font color=#00FF00 size=3>Input</font>  
              </td>
              <td > 
                <input type=text name=input1 size=60>
                </br>
              </td>
              <td>    
                <font color=#000000 size=3>Result</font> 
              </td>
              <td> 
                <input type=text name=hash size=60>
                </br>
              </td>
              <td>  
                <input type=button value="MD5 It!" onclick="hash.value = hex_md5(input1.value)">
                </br>
              </td> 
            </form>

        <script>

         /*
         * A JavaScript implementation of the RSA Data Security, Inc. MD5 Message
         * Digest Algorithm, as defined in RFC 1321.
         * Version 2.1 Copyright (C) Paul Johnston 1999 - 2002.
         * Other contributors: Greg Holt, Andrew Kepert, Ydnar, Lostinet
         * Distributed under the BSD License
         * See http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5 for more info.
         */
        /*
         * Configurable variables. You may need to tweak these to be compatible with
         * the server-side, but the defaults work in most cases.
         */
        var hexcase = 0; /* hex output format. 0 - lowercase; 1 - uppercase */
        var b64pad = ""; /* base-64 pad character. "=" for strict RFC compliance */
        /* var chrsz = 8; */
        /* bits per input character. 8 - ASCII; 16 - Unicode */
        var chrsz = 16; /* bits per input character. 8 - ASCII; 16 - Unicode */
        /*
         * These are the functions you'll usually want to call
         * They take string arguments and return either hex or base-64 encoded strings
         */
        function hex_md5(s) {
           return binl2hex(core_md5(str2binl(s), 
                            s.length * chrsz));
        }

        function b64_md5(s) {
            return binl2b64(core_md5(str2binl(s), s.length * chrsz));
        }

        function str_md5(s) {
            return binl2str(core_md5(str2binl(s), s.length * chrsz));
        }

        function hex_hmac_md5(key, data) {
            return binl2hex(core_hmac_md5(key, data));
        }

        function b64_hmac_md5(key, data) {
            return binl2b64(core_hmac_md5(key, data));
        }

        function str_hmac_md5(key, data) {
            return binl2str(core_hmac_md5(key, data));
        }
        /*
         * Perform a simple self-test to see if the VM is working
         */
        function md5_vm_test() {
            return hex_md5("abc") == "900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72";
        }
        /*
         * Calculate the MD5 of an array of little-endian words, and a bit length
         */
        function core_md5(x, len) {
            /* append padding */
            x[len >> 5] |= 0x80 << ((len) % 32);
            x[(((len + 64) >>> 9) << 4) + 14] = len;
            var a = 1732584193;
            var b = -271733879;
            var c = -1732584194;
            var d = 271733878;
            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i += 16) {
                var olda = a;
                var oldb = b;
                var oldc = c;
                var oldd = d;
                a = md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x[i + 0], 7, -680876936);
                d = md5_ff(d, a, b, c, x[i + 1], 12, -389564586);
                c = md5_ff(c, d, a, b, x[i + 2], 17, 606105819);
                b = md5_ff(b, c, d, a, x[i + 3], 22, -1044525330);
                a = md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x[i + 4], 7, -176418897);
                d = md5_ff(d, a, b, c, x[i + 5], 12, 1200080426);
                c = md5_ff(c, d, a, b, x[i + 6], 17, -1473231341);
                b = md5_ff(b, c, d, a, x[i + 7], 22, -45705983);
                a = md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x[i + 8], 7, 1770035416);
                d = md5_ff(d, a, b, c, x[i + 9], 12, -1958414417);
                c = md5_ff(c, d, a, b, x[i + 10], 17, -42063);
                b = md5_ff(b, c, d, a, x[i + 11], 22, -1990404162);
                a = md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x[i + 12], 7, 1804603682);
                d = md5_ff(d, a, b, c, x[i + 13], 12, -40341101);
                c = md5_ff(c, d, a, b, x[i + 14], 17, -1502002290);
                b = md5_ff(b, c, d, a, x[i + 15], 22, 1236535329);
                a = md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x[i + 1], 5, -165796510);
                d = md5_gg(d, a, b, c, x[i + 6], 9, -1069501632);
                c = md5_gg(c, d, a, b, x[i + 11], 14, 643717713);
                b = md5_gg(b, c, d, a, x[i + 0], 20, -373897302);
                a = md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x[i + 5], 5, -701558691);
                d = md5_gg(d, a, b, c, x[i + 10], 9, 38016083);
                c = md5_gg(c, d, a, b, x[i + 15], 14, -660478335);
                b = md5_gg(b, c, d, a, x[i + 4], 20, -405537848);
                a = md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x[i + 9], 5, 568446438);
                d = md5_gg(d, a, b, c, x[i + 14], 9, -1019803690);
                c = md5_gg(c, d, a, b, x[i + 3], 14, -187363961);
                b = md5_gg(b, c, d, a, x[i + 8], 20, 1163531501);
                a = md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x[i + 13], 5, -1444681467);
                d = md5_gg(d, a, b, c, x[i + 2], 9, -51403784);
                c = md5_gg(c, d, a, b, x[i + 7], 14, 1735328473);
                b = md5_gg(b, c, d, a, x[i + 12], 20, -1926607734);
                a = md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x[i + 5], 4, -378558);
                d = md5_hh(d, a, b, c, x[i + 8], 11, -2022574463);
                c = md5_hh(c, d, a, b, x[i + 11], 16, 1839030562);
                b = md5_hh(b, c, d, a, x[i + 14], 23, -35309556);
                a = md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x[i + 1], 4, -1530992060);
                d = md5_hh(d, a, b, c, x[i + 4], 11, 1272893353);
                c = md5_hh(c, d, a, b, x[i + 7], 16, -155497632);
                b = md5_hh(b, c, d, a, x[i + 10], 23, -1094730640);
                a = md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x[i + 13], 4, 681279174);
                d = md5_hh(d, a, b, c, x[i + 0], 11, -358537222);
                c = md5_hh(c, d, a, b, x[i + 3], 16, -722521979);
                b = md5_hh(b, c, d, a, x[i + 6], 23, 76029189);
                a = md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x[i + 9], 4, -640364487);
                d = md5_hh(d, a, b, c, x[i + 12], 11, -421815835);
                c = md5_hh(c, d, a, b, x[i + 15], 16, 530742520);
                b = md5_hh(b, c, d, a, x[i + 2], 23, -995338651);
                a = md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x[i + 0], 6, -198630844);
                d = md5_ii(d, a, b, c, x[i + 7], 10, 1126891415);
                c = md5_ii(c, d, a, b, x[i + 14], 15, -1416354905);
                b = md5_ii(b, c, d, a, x[i + 5], 21, -57434055);
                a = md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x[i + 12], 6, 1700485571);
                d = md5_ii(d, a, b, c, x[i + 3], 10, -1894986606);
                c = md5_ii(c, d, a, b, x[i + 10], 15, -1051523);
                b = md5_ii(b, c, d, a, x[i + 1], 21, -2054922799);
                a = md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x[i + 8], 6, 1873313359);
                d = md5_ii(d, a, b, c, x[i + 15], 10, -30611744);
                c = md5_ii(c, d, a, b, x[i + 6], 15, -1560198380);
                b = md5_ii(b, c, d, a, x[i + 13], 21, 1309151649);
                a = md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x[i + 4], 6, -145523070);
                d = md5_ii(d, a, b, c, x[i + 11], 10, -1120210379);
                c = md5_ii(c, d, a, b, x[i + 2], 15, 718787259);
                b = md5_ii(b, c, d, a, x[i + 9], 21, -343485551);
                a = safe_add(a, olda);
                b = safe_add(b, oldb);
                c = safe_add(c, oldc);
                d = safe_add(d, oldd);
            }
            return Array(a, b, c, d);
        }
        /*
         * These functions implement the four basic operations the algorithm uses.
         */
        function md5_cmn(q, a, b, x, s, t) {
            return safe_add(bit_rol(safe_add(safe_add(a, q), safe_add(x, t)), s), b);
        }

        function md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x, s, t) {
            return md5_cmn((b & c) | ((~b) & d), a, b, x, s, t);
        }

        function md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x, s, t) {
            return md5_cmn((b & d) | (c & (~d)), a, b, x, s, t);
        }

        function md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x, s, t) {
            return md5_cmn(b ^ c ^ d, a, b, x, s, t);
        }

        function md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x, s, t) {
            return md5_cmn(c ^ (b | (~d)), a, b, x, s, t);
        }
        /*
         * Calculate the HMAC-MD5, of a key and some data
         */
        function core_hmac_md5(key, data) {
            var bkey = str2binl(key);
            if (bkey.length > 16) bkey = core_md5(bkey, key.length * chrsz);
            var ipad = Array(16),
                opad = Array(16);
            for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
                ipad[i] = bkey[i] ^ 0x36363636;
                opad[i] = bkey[i] ^ 0x5C5C5C5C;
            }
            var hash = core_md5(ipad.concat(str2binl(data)), 512 + data.length * chrsz);
            return core_md5(opad.concat(hash), 512 + 128);
        }
        /*
         * Add integers, wrapping at 2^32. This uses 16-bit operations internally
         * to work around bugs in some JS interpreters.
         */
        function safe_add(x, y) {
            var lsw = (x & 0xFFFF) + (y & 0xFFFF);
            var msw = (x >> 16) + (y >> 16) + (lsw >> 16);
            return (msw << 16) | (lsw & 0xFFFF);
        }
        /*
         * Bitwise rotate a 32-bit number to the left.
         */
        function bit_rol(num, cnt) {
            return (num << cnt) | (num >>> (32 - cnt));
        }
        /*
         * Convert a string to an array of little-endian words
         * If chrsz is ASCII, characters >255 have their hi-byte silently ignored.
         */
        function str2binl(str) {
            var bin = Array();
            var mask = (1 << chrsz) - 1;
            for (var i = 0; i < str.length * chrsz; i += chrsz)
            bin[i >> 5] |= (str.charCodeAt(i / chrsz) & mask) << (i % 32);
            return bin;
        }
        /*
         * Convert an array of little-endian words to a string
         */
        function binl2str(bin) {
            var str = "";
            var mask = (1 << chrsz) - 1;
            for (var i = 0; i < bin.length * 32; i += chrsz)
            str += String.fromCharCode((bin[i >> 5] >>> (i % 32)) & mask);
            return str;
        }
        /*
         * Convert an array of little-endian words to a hex string.
         */
        function binl2hex(binarray) {
            var hex_tab = hexcase ? "0123456789ABCDEF" : "0123456789abcdef";
            var str = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < binarray.length * 4; i++) {
                str += hex_tab.charAt((binarray[i >> 2] >> ((i % 4) * 8 + 4)) & 0xF) + hex_tab.charAt((binarray[i >> 2] >> ((i % 4) * 8)) & 0xF);
            }
            return str;
        }
        /*
         * Convert an array of little-endian words to a base-64 string
         */
        function binl2b64(binarray) {
            var tab = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
            var str = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < binarray.length * 4; i += 3) {
                var triplet = (((binarray[i >> 2] >> 8 * (i % 4)) & 0xFF) << 16) | (((binarray[i + 1 >> 2] >> 8 * ((i + 1) % 4)) & 0xFF) << 8) | ((binarray[i + 2 >> 2] >> 8 * ((i + 2) % 4)) & 0xFF);
                for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    if (i * 8 + j * 6 > binarray.length * 32) str += b64pad;
                    else str += tab.charAt((triplet >> 6 * (3 - j)) & 0x3F);
                }
            }
            return str;
        }


        </script>

            </body>
        </html>
```